# how to read & write my usb device data using usb4java

Tags: java, usb4java

I want to read and write sandisk usb data using usb4java lib in java.

i can get usb device list.

but i don't know how to read my usb data.

This is my dump usblist code.

```
{
    // Create the libusb context
    Context context = new Context();

    // Initialize the libusb context
    int result = LibUsb.init(context);
    if (result < 0)
    {
        throw new LibUsbException("Unable to initialize libusb", result);
    }

    // Read the USB device list
    DeviceList list = new DeviceList();
    result = LibUsb.getDeviceList(context, list);
    if (result < 0)
    {
        throw new LibUsbException("Unable to get device list", result);
    }

    try
    {
        // Iterate over all devices and list them
        for (Device device: list)
        {
            int address = LibUsb.getDeviceAddress(device);
            int busNumber = LibUsb.getBusNumber(device);
            DeviceDescriptor descriptor = new DeviceDescriptor();
            result = LibUsb.getDeviceDescriptor(device, descriptor);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                throw new LibUsbException(
                    "Unable to read device descriptor", result);
            }
            System.out.format(
                "Bus %03d, Device %03d: Vendor %04x, Product %04x%n",
                busNumber, address, descriptor.idVendor(),
                descriptor.idProduct());
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Ensure the allocated device list is freed
        LibUsb.freeDeviceList(list, true);
    }

    // Deinitialize the libusb context
    LibUsb.exit(context);
}
```

And this code print out all usb device.

But i want to check my sandisk device once.

How to change my code?

Answer (score 0):

think u have to sniff OS requests during writing and reading data using kernel usb driver. and after that u should to send the same requests to your device.